# Delete /comment ssh key in a remote machine

Tags: linux, shell, ssh, sed

I want to delete/comment one of the ssh key in my remote server .
current node = node1
remote node = node2
In node one I have  pub file and the content of the pub file need to delete from remote node /home/cloud-user/.ssh/authorized_keys . Tried with sed command but its not worked. Below Command tried in my setup  .

test1

pub file name = cluster.pub
(content of pub includes space )

```
key=$(cat  /opt/key/cluster.pub)
ssh -i key.pem node2 "sed -i 's/$key/#$key/g'  /home/cloud-user/.ssh/authorized_keys"
```

error msg

```
sed: -e expression #1, char 0: no previous regular expression
```

test2

copied the cluster.pub into node2:/tmp/

```
ssh -i key.pem node2   "key= cat '/tmp/cluster_login.pub' ;sed -e 's/${key}/#${key}/'    /home/cloud-user/.ssh/authorized_keys"
```

error msg

```
sed: -e expression #1, char 230: unknown option to `s'
```

Looks like while running in remote shell sed command is executing in a different method .

Comment: The first error will happen if `$key` is empty. Put `set -x` at the beginning of the script to see a trace with variables expanded.

Comment: In the second code you're missing `$()` around `cat /tmp/cluster_login.pub`. You also need to escape all the `$` characters so they'll be sent to the server, not ecxxpanded locally.

Comment: It would be easier if you put the remote code in a remote script. Then you could do `ssh node2 /path/to/script`

Comment: if there are unexpected chars for regexp
https://askubuntu.com/questions/395602/how-to-replace-strings-in-file-without-regex

Answer (score 0):

tried the below option which is worked for me .

```
ssh node2 "sed -i '/$(echo "$var" | sed 's/[\/&]/\\&/g')/ s/^/#/' /home/cloud-user/.ssh/authorized_keys"
```